# Which religious texts cause some Jews to focus and worship the material gains in this life (creation) rather than to Hashem (the creator)?

Tags: rabbis, avodah-zarah, priorities, olam-haba-world-to-come, sheker-false

Please see [this article](http://www.app.com/story/news/investigations/watchdog/2017/06/26/lakewood-welfare-fraud/424127001/) in Asbury Park Press regarding welfare fraud by rabbis.

Also, years ago when Christy was a NJ state prosecutor there was another [roundup of rabbis](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/07/24/nyregion/24jersey.html?pagewanted=all) in a New Jersey corruption scheme.

As rabbis who are supposed to be religious leaders, they should know the difference between following Moshe and Hashem vs. worshiping the golden calf.   See Exodus 32 1-5 and Exodus 20 22-23. The golden calf being a metaphor for materialism.

While there may be nothing wrong with pursuing materialism as a means to improve ones existence, there could be contradictions to the Torah if material gains is not the means but the ends.  In other words, worshiping the creation symbolized by the golden calf, rather than the creator.

As an outsider I have always wondered why this paradox existed.  Are there other religious texts in Judaism that conflict with said verses in Exodus of the Torah and emphasize striving for worldly gains as an ends, thus in effect worshiping the creation as a false god ?

Comment: "much of Jewry today focus on materialism and gains in this life even though this may contradict the Torah." You're probably biased by only hearing about the bad cases. Most Jews don't commit federal crimes or welfare fraud.

Comment: I think you have become plagued by old anti-semitic stereotypes. The statement that "much of Jewry today focus on materialism and gains" is certainly not true.

Comment: Please clarify what message you see in the Torah which you are seeking to contrast, and how you see it in the Torah. "following Moshe and Hashem vs. worshiping the golden calf" is rather vague, and it is not clear how that applies here. Please clarify. In the meantime, VTC as unclear.

Comment: Give me a break.  Criminals come in all religious stripes, from the fraudsters to the killers to the child molesters.  The press loves to dwell on the religion of the particular offender when they have a big fish.  It's supposedly part of the "news", but it tends to just..i don't know..try and make people feel superior because they aren't part of the group that that particular criminal is(?).  Not "fake news", but "divisive news", IMO.

Comment: Are you indicating that the golden calf narrative is meant to preach against materialism? On what basis do you suggest this? Are you looking for any sources that stress material reward? The Torah is full of promises of material reward and punishment!

Comment: @mevaqesh I'm sorry for the confusion.  Due to limited space in the comment section, I will update the question with more clear explanations and references.  Please allow some time for this compilation.

Comment: Okay. Best of luck.

Comment: @mevaqesh yes, I see why you wished me luck.  I assumed that heaven and hell eschatology and the day of resurrection and judgement was covered in Genesis but after searching this and the entire Pentateuch I found little mention at all.  I thank you for the link to Olam Ha Ba.  And I now understand the reason for the paradox.  I was thinking about re-wording the question to not mention the hereafter but making correct choices of worshiping the creator rather than the creation.  Or I can just pull the discussion.  What do you suggest?

Comment: @msh it ought be permitted if it gets a question opened. While closed the q and a are of essentially no value even if upvoted

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'd agree if the edit had been made while the Q was closed. But it's the edited version that was closed: it's my reverting that may get the question reopened.

Comment: @mevaqesh OK, I removed the mention of the afterlife, so I am just asking if there are verses in the Old Testament that contradict the allegorical prohibition in Exodus 20 22-23.  Please, let me know if more clarification is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there other religious texts in Judaism that conflict with the Torah and emphasize striving for worldly gains as priority?

I've never seen any and highly doubt there are. Rather, the explanation is undoubtedly in most cases that the spirit is willing but the flesh is weak (to quote another religion's text): they probably want to do the right thing but find themselves tempted not to. I know that's why I do the wrong thing when I do.

One must be careful: as *Haamek Davar* comments to Genesis 6:3, allowing one's desires to overpower his intellect too often can weaken the latter to the point of ineffectiveness.